# Can I use an existing instance of a class to create a new object of an extended subclass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

Is it possible to use an existing instance of a class to create a new object of an extended subclass?

In the example below, I have a `Rectangle` object, `r`. I'd like to create a new `CompanyRectangle` object, `cr`, which starts with identical properties and methods of Rectangle, and then adds more on top of those.

The example below works, but all the properties must be explicitly copied in the `CompanyRectangle` constructor. Is it possible to do this in a way that automatically copies all the properties over?

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Rectangle';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

  }
  update() {
    // Has a bunch of other properties set
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 1;
    this.c = 2;
    this.d = 3;
  }
}

class CompanyRectangle extends Rectangle {
  // Use an existing rectangle (r) as a base for the extended rectangle
  constructor(r) {
    super(r.height, r.width);

    // copy over all the other properties that have been set
    this.a = r.a;
    this.b = r.b;
    this.c = r.c;
    this.d = r.d;

    this.name = 'CompanyRectangle';
  }
}

const r = new Rectangle(4, 2);
r.update(); // set the other properties

// create a new CompanyRectangle object, copying all the properties from 'r'
const cr = new CompanyRectangle(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the update method from `Rectangle class` in `CompanyRectangle` constructor to copy all properties from superclass to subclass;

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.name = 'Rectangle';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

  }
  update() {
    // Has a bunch of other properties set
    this.a = 0;
    this.b = 1;
    this.c = 2;
    this.d = 3;
  }
}

class CompanyRectangle extends Rectangle {
  // Use an existing rectangle (r) as a base for the extended rectangle
  constructor(r) {
    super(r.height, r.width);
    // update method from super class here
    super.update(this);
    

    this.name = 'CompanyRectangle';
  }
}

const r = new Rectangle(4, 2);
r.update(); // set the other properties



// create a new CompanyRectangle object, copying all the properties from 'r'
const cr = new CompanyRectangle(r); 
console.log(cr);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually quite similar to what I'm doing at the moment. However this solution does not automatically copy the properties over (each property/group of properties need to be set via a function call)

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width, otherProperties) {
      this.name = 'Rectangle';
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
        if (otherProperties) {
            this.a = otherProperties.a;
            this.b = otherProperties.b;
            this.c = otherProperties.c;
            this.d = otherProperties.d;
        }
    }
    update() {
      // Has a bunch of other properties set
      this.a = 0;
      this.b = 1;
      this.c = 2;
      this.d = 3;
    }
  }
  
  class CompanyRectangle extends Rectangle {
    // Use an existing rectangle (r) as a base for the extended rectangle
    constructor(r) {
      super(r.height, r.width, r);
  
      // copy over all the other properties that have been set
      this.name = 'CompanyRectangle';
    }
  }
  
  const r = new Rectangle(4, 2);
  r.update(); // set the other properties
  
  // create a new CompanyRectangle object, copying all the properties from 'r'
  const cr = new CompanyRectangle(r);
  console.log(cr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I cannot modify the `Rectangle` class definition as the rectangles are being provided by an external library.